# How to cache a product collection in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cache, product-collection

Currently i load a product collection under certain categories, for example:

```
$collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => array('2','4')));
$collection
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('e.attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $collection->getSelect()->where('e.attribute_set_id = "'.$attributeSetId.'" AND final_price > 0');
```

the problem with this collection, that it will  query like 3000++ product data, can i cache this collection ?